# Permutation testing on a dataset of three groups

Tags: r, statistics, permutation

I want to perform permutation testing (order doesn't matter) using Monte Carlo simulation on a dataset that exists out of three groups. Under the null hypothesis, the placement of the data in the three groups does not matter so I could compute the test statistic for each possible combination and find the distribution function of the statistic.

I have tried using the function combn in a for-loop, but the problem is that I get many duplicates which are hard to remove since my data is in three vectors, and the first vector could be a duplicate but the latter two are not e.g., additionally instead of getting the required (3!)^7 = 279.936 unique permutations I would compute 116280*3432 (=399.072.960) test statistics.

I didn't provide the test statistic because it doesn't really seem relevant, I want to do this exercise myself but I need some help finding all the combinations into which I can divide the vector of data.

```
#dataset
A <- c(2.90,2.56,2.88,2.73,2.50,3.18,2.83)
B <- c(2.97,2.45,2.76,2.20,2.16,2.89,2.87)
C <- c(2.67,2.62,1.84,2.33,1.27,2.39,2.39)
z <- c(A,B,C)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use [**appropriate formatting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738) in the future, this time I've helped you.

Comment: Can you please explain why `(3!)^7`, and not `3^21`?

Comment: I don't really see how it would be 3^21, wouldn't that only be the case if it mattered where I placed them (i.e. which spot from 1 to 7) in each of the three groups?

I thought it was (3!)^7 because I can place patient 1 from group A in any of the groups, and then that leaves me place patient 1 from group B into either of the two remaining groups and patient 1 from the last group in the remaining group.

Comment: @user607032 I think you're making a mistake. You'll apply permutation under null, right? Then you have 21 observations from same distribution, and you can assign them to any of the three groups. So, for each observation, there are 3 choices and hence `3^21` choices. I don't think it makes sense to permute only the first patients among themselves, then the second patients, and so on.